# Accessing a random image via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, uploads

The goal with this is to create a random banner, managed in the wp admin.  I can create a banner solution in the wp admin without an issue but need a little help on the ajax side.

I have an image http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-name.jpg

I created a random_banner function in functions.php.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_random_banner', 'random_banner' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_random_banner', 'random_banner' );

function random_banner() {
    $image = file_get_contents( 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image-name.jpg' );
    header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg;' );
    header( "Content-Length: " . strlen( $image ) );
    echo $image;
}
```

BTW I have tested this outside of wp and it works great.

Anyway, I then link to this function in an image src like:

```
<img src="http://example.com//wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=random_banner">
```

This currently returns a broken image icon in chrome.  The permissions on my uploads folder is 775.

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: normally you need to `exit;` the ajax

Comment: a simpler method would be to pass an URL back and set the src attribute in your javascript. or even simpler would be to pass all of the images to the script via `wp_localize_script` and randomly selecting one in js. requesting a static image is much faster than loading all of WordPress just to end up outputting an image.

Comment: thanks @jycr753.  I added that, but that didn't solve the broken image.

Comment: @Milo I am open to this, but the admin experience is that they will set this url in the admin for a banner.  The url gets output in the template for the banner image.  And I don't have control over the template, so this has to be pretty flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your `src`;

```
<img src="http://example.com//wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=random_banner">
```

Try this one:

```
<img src="http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=random_banner">
```

or

```
<img src="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=random_banner' ); ?>">
```

You can also use a query to get a random image.

### AJAX

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_random_banner', 'random_banner' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_random_banner', 'random_banner' );

function random_banner() {

    // search for 1 random image

    $image_ids = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'numberposts'    => 1,
            'orderby'        => 'rand',
            'fields'         => 'ids',
        ) );

    // convert id to url

    $images = array_map( "wp_get_attachment_url", $image_ids );

    $image_id = $image_ids[ 0 ];
    $image_url = $images[0];

    // make sure path is readable -- if not, stop!

    // this won't work with URL :(
    // if( !is_readable($image_url)) {
    //    wp_die( "File is not readable: $image_url" );
    // }

    $image    = file_get_contents( $image_url );
    $type     = get_post_mime_type( $image_id );
    if ( empty ( $type ) ) {
        $type = "image/jpg";
    }

    // output headers and image data

    nocache_headers();
    header( "Content-type: $type;" );
    header( "Content-Length: " . strlen( $image ) );

    echo $image;
    die();
}
```

### Update | Endpoint Alternate

Skip the AJAX call and just create an API endpoint for your random image function using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

**IMAGE**

```
<img src="http://example.com/api/images/random">
```

**PHP**

```
/**
 * Creates endpoint to select random image from Library
 *
 * http://example.com/api/images/random
 *
 */
if ( ! class_exists( 'Endpoint_RandomImage' ) ):
    /**
     * The code that registers the endpoint and handles the result
     */
    class Endpoint_RandomImage {

        const ENDPOINT_NAME       = 'api/images/random'; // endpoint to capture
        const ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME = '__api_images_random'; // turns to param

        // WordPress hooks
        public function run() {
            add_filter( 'query_vars', array( $this, 'add_query_vars' ), 0 );
            add_action( 'parse_request', array( $this, 'sniff_requests' ), 0 );
            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'add_endpoint' ), 0 );
        }

        // Add public query vars
        public function add_query_vars( $vars ) {
            $vars[] = static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME;
            $vars[] = 'extra';

            return $vars;
        }

        // Add API Endpoint
        public function add_endpoint() {
            add_rewrite_rule( '^' . static::ENDPOINT_NAME . '?$', 'index.php?' . static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME . '=1', 'top' );
            add_rewrite_rule( '^' . static::ENDPOINT_NAME . '/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?' . static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME . '=1&extra=$matches[1]', 'top' );
// --->
            flush_rewrite_rules( true ); //// <---------- REMOVE THIS WHEN DONE TESTING
// --->
        }

        // Sniff Requests
        public function sniff_requests( $wp_query ) {

            global $wp;

            if ( isset( $wp->query_vars[ static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME ] ) ) {
                $this->handle_request(); // handle it
            }
        }

        // Handle Requests
        protected function handle_request() {
            global $wp;

            $image_ids = get_posts(
                array(
                    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                    'numberposts'    => 1,
                    'orderby'        => 'rand',
                    'fields'         => 'ids',
                ) );

            // convert ids to urls
            // $images = array_map( "wp_get_attachment_url", $image_ids );

            // convert ids to paths
            $images = array_map( "get_attached_file", $image_ids );

            $image_id   = $image_ids[ 0 ];
            $image_path = $images[ 0 ];

            // make sure url is readable -- if not, stop!
            if ( ! is_readable( $image_path ) ) {
                wp_die( "File is not readable: $image_path" );
            }

            $image = file_get_contents( $image_path );
            $type  = get_post_mime_type( $image_id );
            if ( empty ( $type ) ) {
                $type = "image/jpg";
            }

            // output headers and image data

            nocache_headers();
            header( "Content-type: $type;" );
            header( "Content-Length: " . strlen( $image ) );

            echo $image;
            die();
        }
    }

    $ep = new Endpoint_RandomImage();
    $ep->run();

endif; // Endpoint_RandomImage
```

---

### Endpoint Alternate #2

```
<img src="http://example.com/api/random-banner/">
```

Using the rewrites + query tags.

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists( 'Prefix_API' ) ) {

    class Prefix_API {

        function __invoke() {
            add_action( 'init', array ( $this, 'prefix__init' ) );
            add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array ( $this, 'prefix__pre_get_posts' ) );
        }

        /**
         * Register a rewrite endpoint for the API.
         */
        function prefix__init() {
            // add tags with `_` prefix to avoid screwing up query
            add_rewrite_tag( '%_api_action%', '([a-zA-Z\d\-_+]+)' );

            // create URL rewrite
            add_rewrite_rule( '^api/([a-zA-Z\d\-_+]+)/?', 'index.php?_api_action=$matches[1]', 'top' );

            // required once after rules added/changed
            flush_rewrite_rules( true );
        }

        /**
         * Handle data (maybe) passed to the API endpoint.
         *
         * @param $query
         */
        function prefix__pre_get_posts( $query ) {

            if ( isset( $query->query_vars[ '_api_action' ] ) ) {

                switch ( $query->query_vars[ '_api_action' ] ) {
                    case 'random-banner';
                        $this->prefix__show_random_image();
                        break;
                }

                // kill the request on an API action call
                die();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Show random image
         *
         * @see http://example.com/api/random-banner/
         */
        function prefix__show_random_image() {
            $image_ids = get_posts( array (
                'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                'numberposts'    => 1,
                'orderby'        => 'rand',
                'fields'         => 'ids',
            ) );

            // convert ids to urls
            // $images = array_map( "wp_get_attachment_url", $image_ids );

            // convert ids to paths
            $images = array_map( "get_attached_file", $image_ids );

            $image_id   = $image_ids[ 0 ];
            $image_path = $images[ 0 ];

            // make sure url is readable -- if not, stop!
            if ( ! is_readable( $image_path ) ) {
                wp_die( "File is not readable: $image_path" );
            }

            $image = file_get_contents( $image_path );
            $type  = get_post_mime_type( $image_id );
            if ( empty ( $type ) ) {
                $type = "image/jpg";
            }

            // output headers and image data

            nocache_headers();
            header( "Content-type: $type;" );
            header( "Content-Length: " . strlen( $image ) );

            echo $image;
            die();
        }

    }

    // create api instance
    $api = new Prefix_API();

    // initialize the api hooks
    $api();
}
```

---

### REST API

```
<img src="http://example.com/wp-json/prefix/v1/random-image/">
```

This version uses a [custom REST API route](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/).

```
/**
 * Register the REST route.
 * 
 * @see http://example.com/wp-json/prefix/v1/random-image/ 
 */
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'prefix/v1', '/random-image/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET, POST',
        'callback' => 'prefix__show_random_image',
        'show_in_index' => false,
    ) );
} );

/**
 * Show random image
 */
function prefix__show_random_image(){
    $image_ids = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'numberposts'    => 1,
            'orderby'        => 'rand',
            'fields'         => 'ids',
        ) );

    // convert ids to urls
    // $images = array_map( "wp_get_attachment_url", $image_ids );

    // convert ids to paths
    $images = array_map( "get_attached_file", $image_ids );

    $image_id   = $image_ids[ 0 ];
    $image_path = $images[ 0 ];

    // make sure url is readable -- if not, stop!
    if ( ! is_readable( $image_path ) ) {
        wp_die( "File is not readable: $image_path" );
    }

    $image = file_get_contents( $image_path );
    $type  = get_post_mime_type( $image_id );
    if ( empty ( $type ) ) {
        $type = "image/jpg";
    }

    // output headers and image data

    nocache_headers();
    header( "Content-type: $type;" );
    header( "Content-Length: " . strlen( $image ) );

    echo $image;
    die();
}
```

Comment: the typo was an accident when I replaced my real url with the example url.  This still displays a broken image icon.

Comment: Try this version. It should tell you if the file is readable or not in the output. Just access it directly first.

Comment: I updated to your new code but no change.  How should it "tell" me if the file is unreadable?

Comment: It will kill the process and only output the words "File is not readable". I'd give you an example to moving to an Endpoint but I have to run. This does work for me locally.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, and the idea to leverage an endpoint vs an ajax url.  Much cleaner.

Comment: Thumbs up for endpoint alternate.

Comment: Yup, just found your answer for my project but for external image that I combine with curl.

Comment: @Jevuska - 2 more versions added. Take your pick.

Comment: Is there a way to return an image from the REST API endpoint without using `echo`? Seems like a bit of a hack

Comment: @nfw - Seems like simple PHP after you know what you want. Something like `readfile` could output any info that it reads instead of buffering data in memory first.